# Unexpected $end

Tags: php, registration

I am trying to make a registration form, but get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/henrirkm/public_html/login/makemyaccount.php on line 91

Can somebody help me?

```
    session_start();

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server

    include "../includes/connect.php";

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $fullname = clean($_POST['fullname']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = clean($_POST['cpassword']);
    $email = clean($_POST['email']);

//Input Validations
if($fullname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Enter your name';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Enter username';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Enter password';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($cpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please fill in password confirmation';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'The passwords did not match';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Fill in email';
    $errflag = true;
}

//Check for duplicate login ID
if($username != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM blog_users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}


if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: register.php");
    exit();
}else {
        $qry = "INSERT INTO `blog_users`(`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$fullname','$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    session_write_close();
                    header("location: avatar.php");
                    exit();
    }
    else {
        die("Sorry, but something wrong happend. Please contact admin-");
    }
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to end the file with an (additional) `}`.

```
    exit();
}else {
        $qry = "INSERT INTO `blog_users`(`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$fullname','$email')";
```

this else there wasn't closed.

Comment: What a fool i am... :) Thanks!